# Move Constructor - invalid type for defaulted constructor VS 2013

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2013

I was reading regarding move constructor and I did this code in VS 2013...

```
class Student
{
    unique_ptr<string> pName_;

public:
    Student(string name) : pName_(new string(name)) { }
    ~Student() { }
    Student(Student&&) = default;  // Here I get the error.
    void printStudentName(void) { cout << *pName_ << endl; }
};

int main(void)
{
    vector<Student> persons;

    Student p = Student("Nishith");
    persons.push_back(std::move(p));
    persons.front().printStudentName();

    return 0;
}
```

I get the "`Student::Student(Student&& )` : is not a special member function which can be defaulted" when I tried to compile it...

Can anyone explain me why I am getting this error?

Comment: Better also add the C++ base tag. Anyway, you know using dynamic allocation for the string is a complete waste?

Comment: You meant in visual studio, right?

Comment: @Deduplicator: Okay, point taken. Yes I meant Visual Studio 2013.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Because the VS2013 compiler doesn't support defaulted move constructors.

See the following note [from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn457344.aspx):

> Visual Studio does not support defaulted move constructors or
>   move-assignment operators as the C++11 standard mandates. For more
>   information, see the Defaulted and Deleted functions section of
>   [Support For C++11 Features (Modern
>   C++)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx).

Comment: I expected that, I also searched MSDN, but didn't find the proper link... Yes, Defaulted and Deleted Functions section under the link says that. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: This answer is misleading.  VS2013 _does_ generate move constructors by default, however, move constructors cannot be defaulted.  They are different things.

Comment: @MooingDuck Thanks. I have made an appropriate edit.

Comment: How do I resolve this error? @RogerRowland