# STL containers and large amounts of data

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, stl, unordered-map

I have a large collection of data that is read into memory - temporarily, but necessary for the system.

I have been checking the performance of `std::vector` as well as `std::unordered_map`.
For `std::vector` I used a `struct` of type:

```
struct information{
    std::string name;
    unsigned int offset;
}
```

For `std::unordered_map` I used the `std::string` for the key and the `unsigned int offset` for the value.

If, let's say, 2 000 000 of these are loaded into memory, I tried the following and got these results:

**`std::vector:`**

On random string, never really larger than 32 characters if a reserve was called on the vector.

```
std::vector<information> vec;
vec.reserve(2500000);
```

The insertion

```
vec.push_back({dataName, offset});
```

is quite fast.  Trying to find data is very slow though.  The find was implemented like this:

```
auto it = std::find_if(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [&name](information &info) -> bool {return info.name == name); });
```

Which makes sense seeing that it is a large vector and the correct `struct` is found on a name compare.  But it was extremely poor performance.  The memory used was fine - I assume a part of the memory growth was due to the `std::string` size resizing.

My question on the vector implementation is: Is there a way to increase the look up time?  I know that a vector can be sorted to increase your look-up time, but then you lose time in sorting the vector.  Especially on a vector of this size.

**`std::unordered_map`:**

The insertion

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, unsigned int> unordMap;
unordMap.reserve(2500000);
unordMap.emplace(name, offset);
```

takes a very long time.  When reserving space beforehand in an attempt to shorten the insertion time the following happens:

The memory at the end of insertion is a lot more when not calling reserve, without reserve the memory is still a lot more than the vector implementation.  The reserve doesn't really improve insertion time.

Of course the look up is very fast.  My question about the `std::unordered_map` is can the insertion time and memory usage be improved?

If neither of these can be done, then my next question will probably be quite obvious.  Is there a way to get a result in between these two data structures?  What is the best for large amounts of data?

Comment: The time you lost sorting the vector is one time only, if you are doing a lot of look up the sort would not be appreciable. You could later use _binary search_ for look up.

Comment: I believe you mistyped `push_back()` there

Comment: Also, although it might be implied frorm the fact that you chose an `unordered_map`, I'll ask just in case: can you have duplicate strings?

Comment: "Is there a way to increase the look up time"...you mean lookup speed?

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio?

Comment: Best is relative to what you do with it. http://john-ahlgren.blogspot.com/2013/10/stl-container-performance.html (there are also a million other copies of that on the internet).

Comment: An issue with this question is that you ask about 5 questions in it...

Comment: Basically, (imho) optimization is 99% choosing the correct data structures. So what do you want to do with your data? which part needs to be fast? Which part can you wait a bit?

Comment: It depends on how you use the data and why you want to use a map. One potential thing to "get the best of two" is using vector for storage and using map as cache. The map<string, int*> will store latest query's string-pointer pair. This will work fine if your queries have strong time locality. For such large data, you don't expect all data to be queried evenly and there is no point to sort them all in the beginning.

Comment: Yes, I am asking a couple of questions in one. I would like to know which data structure would be the best to use. The two it boiled down to for me was std::vector or std::unordered_map. And yes, I am currently using Visual Studio.

Comment: You are asking whether there's a way to increase lookup time for the std::vector. Are you sure you don't mean _decrease_?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
struct information{
  std::string name;
  unsigned int offset;
  information(information const&)=default;
  information(information&&)=default;
  information(std::string n, unsigned o):name(std::move(n)),offset(o),hash(std::hash<std::string>()(name)) {};
  information():information("",0) {};
  bool operator<( information const& o ) const {
    return tie() < o.tie();
  }
  std::tuple<std::size_t, std::string const&> tie() const { return std::tie(hash, name); }
private:
  std::size_t hash;
};
```

Use the above structure for your `std::vector`.

After adding all the data, `std::sort` it.

To find something matching `name` do this:

```
struct information_searcher {
  struct helper {
    std::tuple<std::size_t, std::string const&> data;
    helper( std::string const& o ):data(std::hash<std::string>()(o), o) {};
    helper( helper const& o ) = default;
    helper( information const& o ):data(o.tie()) {}
    bool operator<( helper const& o ) const { return data < o.data; }
  };
  bool operator()( helper lhs, helper rhs ) const { return lhs < rhs; }
};

information* get_info_by_name( std::string const& name ) {
  auto range = std::equal_range( vec.begin(), vec.end(), information_searcher::helper(name), information_searcher{} );
  if (range.first == range.second) {
    return nullptr;
  } else {
    return &*range.first;
  }
}
```

which is a nearly zero-overhead lookup.

What we do here is hash the strings (for fast comparison), falling back on `std::string` comparison if we have a collision.

`information_searcher` is a class that lets us search the data without having to create an `information` (which would require a wasteful allocation).

`get_info_by_name` returns a pointer -- `nullptr` if not found, and a pointer to the first element with that name otherwise.

Changing `information.name` is impolite, and makes the `hash` field incorrect.

This may use moderately more memory than the naive `std::vector` version.

In general, if your work consists of 'add a bunch of stuff to a table' then 'do a bunch of lookups', your best bet is to build a `std::vector`, sort it in a fast way, then use `equal_range` to do the lookups.  `map` and `unordered_map` are optimized for lots of mixed inserts/deletes/etc.

Comment: Just a note on the defaulted move constructor.  VS2013 doesn't generate a default move constructor.
[Invalid type for defaulted constructor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24573963/move-constructor-invalid-type-for-defaulted-constructor-vs-2013)

Answer (score 1):

The problem with a large vector is the lookup time when you don't know the index of objects you want. One way to improve it is, as you stated, to keep an ordered vector and do binary search on it. That way, lookup time will not be of linear complexity but rather of logarithmic complexity, which saves up quite a lot of time with very large containers. This is the lookup used in `std::map` (the ordered one). You can do a similar binary search using [`std::lower_bound`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound) or [`std::equal_range`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/equal_range) on your `std::vector`.

The problem with a large unordered map is completely different : this kind of container use a hash function and modulus calculation in order to place the elements according to their keys in a standard array. So when you have a n elements in a `std::unordered_map`, it is very unlikely that you only need an n-elements-long array, because some indices will not be filled. You will use at least the greatest index produced by the hash-and-modulo. One way to improve memory usage as well as insertion time is to write your own hash function. But it might be hard depending on what kind of strings you are using.

Comment: `std::hash` produces values over the entire range of `std::size_t`, and `std::unordered_map` does not have that many elements in its array of buckets...

Comment: @Yakk : Thanks, fixed. However, I don't see how your solution makes lookup faster than directly using lower_bound or equal_range. Can you explain (either here, in your answer, or by messaging) ?

Comment: Why I hashed?  Well, comparing two `std::string`s is slow (you have to access memory that isn't nearby (hit), and then you have to walk it until they disagree and/or hit an end (unpredictable branches)).  Comparing two `std::size_t`s in an array is fast (cache coherancy!).  You'll still get branch prediction fails (assuming data is at a random point in the container, which is likely), but a bounded number of them.  Or are you talking about `information_searcher`?  That is so we don't have to copy the `std::string` into an `information`.

Comment: @Yakk : Oh I see how it works now. It is indeed faster to compare `size_t`'s than `string`'s. This is quite a lot specialized for this particular use, but I still learned something. One last thing about your `information_searcher` : could it not be replaced by a call to `tie` like that ? `std::tie(std::hash(name), name)`

Comment: try it -- need either cast-to-tie for information or 4 overloads on comprator.

Answer (score 1):

vector is usually implemented as 'dynamic array' and should be the most memory-efficient.
with good reservation strategy it can have insert of O(1) = fast. Searching is O(n) = very bad.

You can help vector by sorting it (and if you first load then search than I think it would be best - std::sort + std::binary_search).
You can as well implement something like insert-sort using std::lower_bound. insert = O(log n) = good, search = O(log n) = good

map (ordered) can actually do the same work, but may as well be implemented using tree = less memory efficient, access as good as sorted vector (but maybe less reallocation, but in your case, sorted vector is still best)

unordered_map is usually imlemented using hash tables = some memory overhead but fast operations (insertion cannot be that fast as in unsorted vector, but should still be pretty fast). The problen with hashing is that it *can* be fast and even fastest, but may as well be the worst solution (in extreme conditions). The above structures (sorted vector and map/tree are stable, always behave the same - logaritmic complexity).

Answer (score 0):

Well, the optimal solution here would be to create std::map, which is logarithmic in complexity both in insertion and in lookup. Although, I don't see any reason why you wouldn't use std::vector. It is pretty fast when using quick sort to sort even 2M elements, especially if you do it once. std::binary_search is then really fast. Think it over if you need to make a lot of lookups between insertions.

Comment: In what way is `std::map` going to be faster than `std::unordered_map` in the above cases?

Comment: But a map has a lot of memory overhead.  A lot more than a vector. I'll look into sorting the vector.